# Use environment variables with Entity Framework Core Migrations

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

We are using a different database schema name for each environment (e.g. "dev", "test", "prod"), and I'm trying to setup Migrations with Entity Framework Core.

The first thing I did was `Add-Migration Init`, which as expected created a Migration for the initial schema. However, this Migration hard-codes the schema name:

```
migrationBuilder.EnsureSchema(
    name: "dev");

migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "MyTable",
    schema: "dev",
    columns: table => new
    ...
```

I guess I could modify the Migration files generated by `dotnet ef` to use a schema name based on an environment variable, but I'd rather not modify these auto-generated files if possible.

Is there any other way to use an environment-specific schema name?

Comment: @interesting-name-here I don't recall, but I long-since switched to other methods for migrations, such as [DbUp](https://dbup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - EF's tooling was just too basic at the time, and I prefer to use SQL in any case

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL Server supports [`default_schema` for user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql).

You may create different users with different default schemes (also you may restrict this users from accessing "other" schemes) and use different connection strings for different environments.